# usage of "too--for--to--"

Tags: infinitives, transitivity

> The coffee is too hot for me  to drink.
>
> The coffee is too hot for me to drink** it.

I want to know whether I need to put "object" after "infinitive" in "too--for--to" pattern.

In which condition we need to put "object" after "infinitive" in "too--for--to-" pattern?

Comment: No. The first sentence is correct, while the second is possible but a bit infelicitous. You might use that construction for emphasis, though.

Comment: How will the second sentence mean?

Comment: What the second sentence means is same as the first, just with a little more emphasis, as if you were speaking to someone who didn't understand the first time. We commonly add syntax when we want to stress something, or to convey irritation that we have not been understood the first time, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation gives me a clear picture.

Comment: No, it is fine as it is. Non-finite clauses like "for me too drink" in your first example are sometimes called "hollow" clauses because some non-subject element is missing yet recoverable from an antecedent expression; here the missing element is the direct object of "drink", whose antecedent is "the coffee". When we diagram such sentences, we represent the missing element with a "gap": The coffee is too hot for me to drink __"

Comment: @BillJ So is the 2nd sentence acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

What the second sentence means is same as the first, just with a little more emphasis, as if you were speaking to someone who didn't understand the first time. We commonly add syntax when we want to stress something, or to convey irritation that we have not been understood the first time, etc.

No, it is fine as it is. Non-finite clauses like "for me too drink" in your first example are sometimes called "hollow" clauses because some non-subject element is missing yet recoverable from an antecedent expression; here the missing element is the direct object of "drink", whose antecedent is "the coffee". When we diagram such sentences, we represent the missing element with a "gap": The coffee is too hot for me to drink __

Comment: So is the 2nd sentence *The coffee is too hot for me to drink it* acceptable?